# Stuck in redirect loop for google oauth 2 using application owner account

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, gmail, omniauth, google-oauth

I cant login to a website using google oauth.
I have multiple gmail accounts and all seem to work fine but when I try to login through application owner account. It doesnt let me login and keeps me redirecting to the account selection UI. After failure of that account sign in I cant login with any other accounts until I clear my cookies.

Note : I am working with Rails (4.0.5) with omniauth-oauth2 (1.2.0)

Comment: Can you try to add the query string parameter `authuser=X` being X the position of the account when Google prompts which account to use? Maybe this helps you jump out of the redirection loop...